# Replication/Synchronization Library for Occasionally Connected Systems

Tags: .net, synchronization, replication, dial-up, data-synchronization

here is the situation I have a .Net desktop application which stores it's data on local file system (using sqllite). And there is the master database on a remote server which. The desktop application needs to synchronize data to the master database when ever there is a dial up connection to a specif server or when ever there is an internet connection.
Is there a simple library for synchronizing/replicating data for occasionally connected system to/from a master database using dailu-up or internet connection?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using a SQL Server compact edition database on the client side and use Microsoft sync framework's [database synchronization provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb887608) that takes advantage of SQL server 2008's [change tracking mechanism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280462.aspx) (assuming that it SQL server on the server side too) or you can implement a custom sync. provider in the sync framework.